# Git Bash: My Desktop folder not found help me

Tags: bash, git, desktop, cd

```sh
$ cd /Desktop
bash: cd: /Desktop: No such file or directory
```

and `start.` command finally I have got the Desktop folder

Comment: There is already a Desktop folder inside Freizo.

Comment: There is already a Desktop folder inside Freizo. Git Bash: $ cd ~/Desktop/ bash: cd: /c/Users/Freizo/Desktop/: No such file or directory

Comment: Can you locate this directory using the Windows Explorer? You can then use the full path name, for instance `cd /c/....../Desktop`. I just tried it on my Win 10 system and found several directories with this name  (7 in total, for instance  `/c/Users/Default/Desktop` and  `c/Users/fisrona/Desktop`, where _fisrona_ is my login name). In such a case, you have to pick the one you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
```

where ~ represents your home directory.

Comment: which OS you are using ? Linux or Mac ?

Comment: windows 10 using git bash

Comment: Ok, then simply  cd ~/Desktop/ should take you to that directory

Comment: $ cd ~/Desktop/
bash: cd: /c/Users/Freizo/Desktop/: No such file or directory

Comment: There is already a Desktop folder inside Freizo.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `git bash` it does not matter which os you use, your home directory located at `~` and Desktop is under `~/Desktop`

#### Windows

Under windows, it will be mapped to `/c/Users/<your user>/Desktop`

#### Linux based Os

Under unix/linux it will be your /home//Desktop

[image]

Comment: $ cd ~/Desktop/
bash: cd: /c/Users/Freizo/Desktop/: No such file or directory
Freizo ~
$ pwd
/c/Users/Freizo

Comment: what is the output of `cd ~ && pwd`

Comment: run `ls -la` - do you see the Desktop folder in the list?

Comment: What do I do now? please help me

Comment: I don't see Desktop folder , maybe it doesn't exist

Comment: This is your problem, so create it and if you can be kind enought to accet this as answer